# Builtin method of culling all values outside lower and upper, perl array

Tags: perl

I've got an array in perl which contains sorted non-contiguous values. For example: `1 2 3 5 7 11 13 15`.

I want to remove all values that are outside `lower` and `upper`, keeping `lower` and `upper` in the returned selection. My method of doing that looks like this (could probably be improved by using `slice`):

```
my @culledArray;
for ( my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@array); $i++ ) { 
    if ( ( $array[$i] <= $_[1] ) and ( $array[$i] >= $_[0] ) ) { 
       push(@culledArray, $array[$i]);
    }
}
```

where the `lower` and `upper` are contained in `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`, respectively. Is there a perl builtin that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know anything built-in that would do that (that is quite a specific requirement), but you can save yourself some typing by using `grep`:

```
my @culledArray = grep {( $_ <= $_[1] ) and ( $_ >= $_[0] )} @array;
```

If the list is long and you don't want to copy it, finding the start and end indices and using a [slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) might be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This is messy, but my unit tests pass, so it seems to work. Take the lower and upper indexes, based on the fact that `@array` is a sorted list and `$_[0] >= $_[1]`, then create the `@culledArray` from `@array[$lower..$upper]`:

```
my @culledArray;
my $index = 0;
++$index until $array[$index] >= $_[0];
my $lowerIndex = $index;
while (($array[$index] <= $_[1]) and ($index < $#array)) { ++$index; }
my $upperIndex = $index;

@culledArray = @array[$lowerIndex .. $upperIndex];
return \@culledArray;
```

I'd love to know the efficiency of this vs [the answer Mat gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10776755/1084945). I'm almost sure that I don't necessarily traverse the entire `@array` (because I traverse from index of `0` until I find the `$upperIndex`. I'm not sure how the `grep` method in the linked answer works, or how `perl` implements the slicing of `@array` to `@culledArray` in the above code, though.

Comment: If you're looking for efficiency, with a large list, a binary search (since the array is sorted) would be much more efficient than what you propose. `grep` goes through the whole array, so it would be less efficient than your method if there are many elements over the upper bound (and the array is large).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be using percentiles or quantiles? If so then [`Statistics::Descriptive`](https://metacpan.org/module/Statistics%3a%3aDescriptive) may help.

The `percentile` method returns the value and index at that percentile, so you can use code as below

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Statistics::Descriptive;

my @data = qw/ 1 2 3 5 7 11 13 15 /;

my $stat = Statistics::Descriptive::Full->new;
$stat->add_data(@data);
my ($d25, $i25) = $stat->percentile(25);
my ($d75, $i75) = $stat->percentile(75);

my @subset = ($stat->get_data)[$i25 .. $i75];

print "@subset\n";
```

**output**

```
2 3 5 7 11
```